# Does CXF's behavior of treating @FormParams like @QueryParams on a @GET request violate the JAX-RS specification?

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

My company just wasted some serious engineering time tracking down a problem related to `@FormParam`s on a JAX-RS `@GET` method. My thinking was that this should – by definition – not work at all, as form parameters are supposed to be transmitted in a x-www-form--urlencoded **request body** and, per RFC 7231 section 4.3.1, a request body "within a GET request message has no defined semantics" and is supposed to be ignored by the server.

However, we discovered that – at least in CXF – `@FormParam`s on a `@GET` behave the same way as `@QueryParam`s! After much discussion and research, I came across this paragraph in the [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-DealingwithParameters):

> Note that the parameters, marked with @FormParam annotation, can take the values from the query parameters in case, if request body is already consumed. This is defined in JAX-RS specification due to the filters (Spring security, etc) consuming the body and thus JAX-RS form parameters becoming empty. User can optionally deactivate standard behavior through setting "set.form.parameters.from.http.parameters" message property to false.

I assume that the reference to JAX-RS is pointing to section 11.1 in the specification, where it states:

> Servlet filters may trigger consumption of a request body by accessing request parameters. In a servlet
>   container the @FormParam annotation and the standard entity provider for application/x-www-form--urlencoded MUST obtain their values from the servlet request parameters if the request body has already
>   been consumed. Servlet APIs do not differentiate between parameters in the URI and body of a request so
>   URI-based query parameters may be included in the entity parameter.

Now my question is: **Does CXF's behavior of treating `@FormParam`s like `@QueryParam`s on a `@GET` request violate the JAX-RS specification?**

The JAX-RS spec mandates obtaining `@FormParam` values from the request parameters, "if the request body has already been consumed". In a GET request there is no request body to be consumed in the first place, so I would say that this statement does not apply to GET requests at all.

As a minor follow-up question, I'm also curious if someone could clarify what is meant when the spec states that "Servlet APIs do not differentiate between parameters in the URI and body of a request so
URI-based query parameters may be included in the entity parameter" – the servlet APIs that I know can very well distinguish between information in the URI (i.e., `HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()`) from information in the body (i.e., `ServletRequest.getReader()`).

Comment: When they say "do not differentiate", I think it refers to getting _parameters_ from the HttpServletRequest, using any one of the getParameterXxx methods, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect when you use @FormParam with a @GET?  null values? empty values?  Since the Servlet API does not differentiate, I don't see why Jax-RS should?

Comment: @JeffWang I'm expecting this to result in an error, which is what Jersey does in this situation: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/bdada1e/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/model/ResourceMethodValidator.java#L129